# How to create shadow in JSF input field and keep it when the user clicks on it

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript which is used for creating shadow into input field:

```
<!-- input field shadow  -->
    var placeholder = "#{GlassfishController.date}"
    $("input").on({
        focus: function() {
            if (this.value == placeholder) {
                $(this).val("").removeClass("shadow");
            }
        },
        blur: function() {
            if (this.value == "") {
                $(this).val(placeholder).addClass("shadow");
            }
        }
    }).trigger("blur");
```

Now the script displays the time format. But when I click with the mouse in the field the text disappears. I want to modify the script to disappear only when I type key. How I can do this?

Best Wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event:

```
var placeholder = "#{GlassfishController.date}"
$("input").on({
    keypress: function() {
        if (this.value == placeholder) {
            $(this).val("").removeClass("shadow");
        }
    },
    blur: function() {
        if (this.value == "") {
            $(this).val(placeholder).addClass("shadow");
        }
    }
}).trigger("blur");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2qY52/

Comment: Thank you! I would like to ask you one more question. In this example when I click on the input filed the cursor is allays at the end on of the date. Is it possible to modify the script in a way that when I click on the input field the cursor is at the begging of the date?

Comment: Wow this code is huge for this simple operation. Is there any more simple way?

Comment: If you are looking for cross-browser way then unfortunately no.